# Add Job with Jobclass in quartz.net dynamic

Tags: c#, reflection, quartz.net

i build a function to create a job in on quartz.net

The Classname, Jobname and Cronstring a in my application database. Now tihs function create a new job and trigger, but the class name are a string. 
I search with reflaction or equivalent to java with class.forname and i found no solution for my problem.

```
private void newJob(string JobName, string klasse, string parameter,string cronString)
{
        IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.Start();

        ???

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<???> ().WithIdentity(Jobname, "group1").Build();
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .
        .
        .
```

How can i the string "klasse" convert in a class and use it in the JobBuilder.create Statemant?

Comment: You should be able to use Type MyType = Type.GetType("klasse"); .  Then pass MyType into the Create<>.

Answer (score 2):

There is an overload of JobBuilder.Create() that accepts a `Type` parameter, so you can do `JobBuilder.Create(Type.GetType(klasse, true))` to create your job

Comment: If i use this
    IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<Type.GetType(klasse, true)>().WithIdentity("myJob", "group1").Build();

i have the message 

Der <-Operator kann nicht auf Operanden vom Typ "Methodengruppe" und "Type" angewendet werden.